# We don't really trust [symantec] anymore

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

([title is a play on this issue](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/09/12/chrome_66_to_reject_symantec_certs/))

[symantec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/symantec)

95 questions, no excerpt or wiki, and lots of off-topic questions. If there is a specific Symantec product that is on-topic we probably need a more specific tag than this. Most of the questions are about antivirus or their soon-to-be-defunct SSL services (or [this weird one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517998/delete-lines-with-date-older-than-a-specific-date) that has the tag for YOLO?)

Comment: I suspect all those burninate requests are just there to make a good word in the title. I'm guilty of some :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  And by the same time make the site less cluttered.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Now now, let's not get all bogged down in [symantec]s

Comment: 2 people still trust them...

Comment: Do you have an image of said weird question for us lesser mortals with less than 10k who can't see deleted posts yet?

Comment: @EJoshuaS It was a giant data set with a smaller data set the OP wanted. Basically asking how to go from A to B

Answer (score 21):

Most of these questions appear appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) and/or [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour). However, there could be some that involve programming. We should cleanup the tag first, closing off-topic questions and editing others to improve their quality, before we make a final judgment call.

When we are left with a much smaller pile of questions, it's possible we could create one single tag for a specific Symantec module or product to replace all the remaining generic instances.

Comment: Since Synantec's SSL root was blown away, I want to see one on-topic question without a "no" answer to save the tag.